# Keycloak Java adapter - Retrieving roles list

Tags: java, wildfly, keycloak

I need to retrieve the roles associated to user, but I am working with wildfly, I have installed all jar keycloak in wildfly and my Java project, but can I retrieve this list by Java adapter?

Other options is call the rest api like any api by get, post, put, etc. But my first options was Adapters.

I make the authentication by adapters, but I do not find any way to retrieve roles, clients, realms, etc.

I am wrong or the adapter is just to authentications?

Anyone have a good example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, here other way: (retrieve one role by name)

```
Keycloak keycloak = Keycloak.getInstance("http://localhost/auth", "realm-name", "client-name", authorization);

RoleRepresentation role = keycloak.realm("realm-name").clients().get(idOfClient).roles().get(roleName).toRepresentation();
```

To listing all user:

```
UsersResource users = keycloak.realm("realm-name").users();
```

And "authorization" is the string token bearer

"getInstance" have other methods to send for example pass and user.

Answer (score 6):

Set the option `use-resource-role-mappings : true`  in keycloak.json
and you should be able to get roles in servlet as follows

```
 KeycloakPrincipal principal = (KeycloakPrincipal)request.getUserPrincipal();

principal.getKeycloakSecurityContext().getToken().getResourceAccess("testclient").getRoles();
```

You can also get `KeycloakPrincipal` from context like this

```
  Subject subject = (Subject) PolicyContext.getContext("javax.security.auth.Subject.container");
  Set<KeycloakPrincipal> principals = subject.getPrincipals(KeycloakPrincipal.class);
```

and then get the roles

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is still struggling, here's a complete answer:

1. Create a security context producer:

```
@RequestScoped
public class SecurityContextProducer {

    @Inject
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Produces
    public KeycloakSecurityContext getSecurityContext() {
        return ((KeycloakPrincipal) request.getUserPrincipal())
                .getKeycloakSecurityContext();
    }
}
```

2. Use it like this:

```
    @Inject
    private KeycloakSecurityContext keycloakSecurityContext;

    public List<String> getRolesKeycloak() {
        Set<String> roleNames = keycloakSecurityContext.getToken().getRealmAccess().getRoles();
        List<String> targetList = new ArrayList<>(roleNames);
        return targetList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly the topic but I needed to find the roles associated with a specific user and this question pops first with my keywords web search. Here's what worked for me with keycloak client 13.0.1

```java
RealmResource realmResource = keycloak.realm(REALM);
UsersResource usersResource = realmResource.users();
UserResource userResource =  usersResource.get(USER_ID);
RoleMappingResource roleMappingResource = userResource.roles();
// either realmLevel or clientLevel
RoleScopeResource roleScopeResource = roleMappingResource.realmLevel();
List<RoleRepresentation> rolesRepresentation = roleScopeResource.listAll();
```

I didn't find it elsewhere, I hope it can be useful.